# Как портировать liquidFun на Unity?

Tags: c#, c++, unity3d, разработка-игр, расширения

Есть классное расширение для box2d, называется liquidFun https://google.github.io/liquidfun/

К сожалению, из ассет стора пропал его порт. Написано оно на c++. Как я понимаю, физика в Unity построена на box2d, если говорить о 2д.

Подскажите, как портировать библиотеку на Unity?
Вот исходный код библиотеки
https://github.com/google/liquidfun

Comment: Что значиит "как портировать"? Вы какого ответа ждете?

Comment: _ассет стора пропал_, из гуглопоиска тоже пропал? А так, берёте [DllImport] и вперёд.

Comment: Под портированием я имею ввиду "использовать библиотеку в Unity".

Comment: В Гугл поиске никакой информации об использовании на Unity не нашел.